# Get most recent data based on Date but I am stuck on the CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have looked into the suggested similar questions presented by StackOverflow but my question has a twist that I did not see on any of the suggested solutions.

We have a survey on our web app that selected group of individuals are required to complete and submit every year.

Each year, one of the members of this select group opens the survey, enters his/her employee ID for validation.

If this employee has completed this form previously, then his/her most recent record based on date created (dateCreated) partially populates the form for him / her.

If the user has never completed the form, then he/she is presented with a blank form to complete the entire form.

This part seems to work fine.

Prior the the COVID 19 pandemic, the following CASE expression makes it easier to identify whether a user has completed the form the previous year or has never completed the form.

```
CASE WHEN YEAR(d.dateCreated) = YEAR(getdate()) -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as previousYear, 
CASE WHEN YEAR(d.dateCreated) = YEAR(getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as thisYear
```

The pandemic has created a two year gap as a result of this process being halted for two years.

How do I modify the above CASE expression to say that if YEAR(dateCreated) is equal to, or earlier than, last year then 1 else if YEAR(dateCreated) is equal to this year (someone has already submitted this form this year then 1 else 0?

We use the value of 1 or 0 in our asp.net app to determine what information to display to user.

If value is 1 then user has completed this form before, populate the form with the approved records from the database. If this is the first time the user is completing this form, present a completely blank form to him/her.

Below is the complete stored procedure are trying to modify its CASE statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getRecs]
@empID varchar(50)
 AS
  BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT OFF;

     SELECT e.employeeName, e.email, e.emptitle, e.EmpID,s.sourcename, s.sourceaddress,d.dateCreated,sp.spousename, sp.spouseaddress,
       r.reimbursementName,r.reimbursementAddress, h.HonorariaName,h.HonorariaAddress, 
       h.HonorariaName as honoraria,h.HonorariaAddress,h.HonorariaIncome,g.giftName,g.giftAddress,dv.dividentName,dv.dividentAddress,
       o.orgName,o.orgAddress,cr.creditorName, cr.creditorAddress,
       CASE WHEN YEAR(d.dateCreated) = YEAR(getdate()) -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as previousYear, 
       CASE WHEN YEAR(d.dateCreated) = YEAR(getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as thisYear
    FROM Employees e 
    INNER JOIN  SourceDetails s ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN  SpouseDetails sp ON e.EmployeeID = sp.employeeID
    INNER JOIN  DividentDetails dv ON e.EmployeeID = dv.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN  ReimbursementDetails r ON e.EmployeeID = r.employeeID
    INNER JOIN  Honoraria h ON e.EmployeeID = h .EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN  GiftDetails g ON e.EmployeeID = g.employeeID
    INNER JOIN  dateDetails d ON e.EmployeeID = d.employeeID
    INNER JOIN  org o ON e.employeeID = o.employeeID
    INNER JOIN  creditorDetails cr ON e.employeeID = cr.employeeID
    INNER JOIN
       (
        Select e.EmpID, Max(d.dateCreated) AS dateCreated
        From Employees e INNER JOIN dateDetails d ON e.EmployeeID = d.employeeID
        Group BY e.EmpID
       )MaxDates
        On e.empid = MaxDates.EmpID
        And d.dateCreated = MaxDates.dateCreated
    WHERE e.EmpID=@empID
    ORDER By d.dateCreated DESC
   End
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Are you trying to fix column [previousYear], [thisYear], or both? Some sample dates and expected results would be helpful to confirm exactly what you are trying to do. But I think you just are looking for something like ```CASE WHEN YEAR(d.dateCreated) < YEAR(getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as previousYear```

Comment: You can correct your terminology in your question.

Comment: @Stephan and Brian Stork, thank you both great guys for your help. Yes, both of your code actually works but don't I need thisYear column as well four our .net solutions. If previousYear = 1 then user has already completed the form...?

Comment: Actually gentlemen, your solution is not going to work I am afraid. Your solution assumes that at the time the user is completing the form, s/he has not already completed the form. We need to protect against user completing the form in the current year but somehow forgot and tries to do it again. That's why we need to check if the form has already been completed for the current year (thisYear). My apologies for any confusions.

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected results as it's still unclear what exactly you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like you could just ask for the year of d.dateCreated being less than year of getdate().

```
CASE WHEN YEAR(d.dateCreated) < YEAR(getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as previousYear
```

Is there a reason this won't work?

Comment: we need to make sure that the user did not complete the form thisYear, for some reason, forgot s/he has already completed the form and tries to do it again. These things happen and we need to protect against that possibility.

Thank you very much sir for your help

Comment: You leave the other "thisYear" CASE alone. Just modify the one for previousYear.... (I didn't include code I wasn't changing).

Comment: Thank you. I modified like this:
```CASE WHEN YEAR(d.dateCreated) < YEAR(getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as previousYear
CASE WHEN YEAR(d.dateCreated) = YEAR(getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as thisYear`
I need thisYear so we can prevent users from submitting twice. Now, we can say ```If (thisYear)="1" then you have submitted form already. Thankyou for submitting`

Thanks alot for your help. I will give Stephan an upvote since I am not sure who submitted first. I really appreciate you guys' prompt response.